# Azure Active Directory on-behalf-of flow in a microservices solution

Tags: oauth, authorization, azure-active-directory, microservices

I have a microservices solution with an API gateway in front of the microservices. I want authorization to happen at the microservice level. I have a SPA client using implicit flow to acquire a token and call the API. At the API i use the on-behalf-of flow to acquire a token to call the related microservice as the user. So to the microserice it appears to be the user and authorization can be performed.

My question is if I don't use on-behalf-of flow I would need to give the API gateway an app-level permission to access the microservice. If I give the API app-level service-to-service (client credential grant flow) capabilities, then I would have to rely on the gateway API to perform authorization, which seems like a really bad idea. It is also a really bad idea if another API needs to call mine in a similar scenario.

My question is this: what are some other approaches that would allow me to flow the user identity through to the microservice so proper authorization can occur?

I've seen examples of another header being used in Identity Server, but I'm not if that is done due to some lack of on-behalf-of options in Identity Server. Btw, I realize I could pass the user identity as a string, but I would be losing all the signed token benefits that provide a level of certainty that the token hasn't been tampered.

Comment: Do you have an issue with the OBO flow that makes you consider using something else?

Comment: Curious to know which direction you took on this - any updates?

Comment: Likewise, what did you do in the end? I have a very similar requirement and am trying to decide on the best approach. As OBO is for a specific user for a specific set of scopes, does it need to call the authentication server for each request?

Comment: I ended up going with OBO and it has worked fine. I can cache the acquired token at the microservice level to be more efficient, but it still requires some back-and-forth communication with AAD for each user when initially getting the token or refreshing. I guess it comes down to the level of trust and security you want. The OBO approach is fairly straight forward after you get it worked out and makes it so I don't need to trust the calling service. I have to trust AAD, but I'm kind of doing that already.